# Compaq SR2019 noisy fan no message on monitor

Tags: fan, noise

I left my computer running and when came back and switched on my monitor I got a message: No Signal and the computer shut down immediately.

When I tried to reboot, the fan is really noisy, the DVD writer light comes on, but plugging in a USB-stick (with a light), it doesn't light up.

The computer is located in a cupboard and got quite hot and the screen would go pink from time to time.

Does anyone know what it might be and if it's possible to recover my hard disk?

Comment: If the problem isn't in the hard disk, you can just plug the hard disk in another computer. So data recovery is a non-issue. However, I have a bad feeling about the rest of the hardware

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the video is fried. I see that most of the Compaq SR 2019s have integrated video (on the motherboard), but the Compaq web site lists several models with the number SR 2019. Which model do you have?

A bad video will prevent the computer from booting, but your data may be OK. Can you remove the hard drive and insert it into another computer or an external USB drive housing? If so, you may be able to recover your data.